# How to fix the error "Bad Operand Types for Binary Operator '>=' first type: int[] second type int"

Tags: java, knights-tour

**The error is with this line: **

```
if ((board[r + vertical[movenumber]]) <= 8 && board[r + vertical[movenumber]] >= 1)
```

**Whole method if needed: **

```
public void tour()
{

    int starter = 1;

    int start1 = (int)(Math.random() * 8 - 1) + 1;
    int start2 = (int)(Math.random() * 8 - 1) + 1;

    board[start1][start2] = starter;

    int r = start1;
    int c = start2;

    for (int count = 0; count < board[row].length; count++)
    {

        numb[count] = count;

    }

    for (int runs = 2; runs <= 64; runs++)
    {

        int movenumber = (int)(Math.random() * 8 - 1) + 1;

        if ((board[r + vertical[movenumber]]) <= 8 && board[r + vertical[movenumber]] >= 1)
        {

            if (board[r + vertical[movenumber]][c + horizontal[movenumber]] == 0)
            {

                board[r + vertical[movenumber]][c + horizontal[movenumber]] = runs;

                // System.out.println(r + "," + c);

                r = r + vertical[movenumber];
                c = c + horizontal[movenumber];

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty specific - you are trying to compare an array with an `int`.
The `board[r + vertical[movenumber]]` expression is an array (or `int[]`, specifically), because your board is `int[][]`. To make it an `int`, you need to add a second index, just like you do in the following lines: `board[r + vertical[movenumber]][c + horizontal[movenumber]]`.

And from quick glance at the code, I think it should be `r + vertical[movenumber] <= 8` instead.

Comment: Could you please accept an answer if it helped? thanks